# Can't get JSON from another domain using Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsonp, spring-rest

I am trying to use JSONP to get my JSON from another domain that uses the Spring. So, I have written `JsonpControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpControllerAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

    public JsonpControllerAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("games")
@RestController
public class GameController extends BaseGameController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GameController.class);

    private static final String KAFKA_TOPIC = "virto_games";

    private static final String ROOT_URL = ServerConfig.GAMES_HOST + "/games";

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> games(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page
    ) {
        String url = ROOT_URL + "?page=" + page;
        return request.get(url);
    }
}
```

In browser it returns the next JSON:

```
{
    "items":[{
        "id":"1b4a3104-925b-46ac-a2da-2187bbf46e0a",
        "name":"Minecraft",
        "description":"Game",
        "user_id":"ee430ea5-0977-4fc2-b1c4-cc33ddd9db56"
    }],
    "number":0,
    "count":1
}
```

Below my js code is where I am trying to get my JSON:

```
var virtoHost = "http://localhost:8080/";

function getGames() {
    $.ajax({
        url: virtoHost + 'games',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

But it crashes with exception:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
[Learn More]
games:1:8
```

What's wrong? I checked it's a correct JSON and `:` is a standard delimiter.

Comment: That looks like JSON and not JSONP

Comment: How to convert it in JSONP or get JSON? For me no difference it's JSON or JSONP, I need to it worked in some way at least. Cuz I can't request JSON from another server directly.

Comment: You can request JSON in the backend.... You are not calling the 3rd party site in the browser.

Comment: @epascarello I hadn't the backend, it's a reason why I tried to use this method.

Comment: Well a server has to support JSONP if you are calling it directly. Just saying you want JSONP does not mean you get it, the server has to understand it needs to be wrapped in the callback.

Comment: [It says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) I can use it to receive data from another domain

Comment: Yes BUT the api you call has to support it.

Comment: @epascarello I ask at least how to change my code to support it because from tutorials are that I read for Spring it sais about `@ControllerAdvice` only

Comment: So you control the server code that is spitting out the JSON?

Comment: Yeah, it's my servers... It returns a simple JSON, I can change a response in my aggregation server's controller (`GameController`).

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten my error... I didn't know that `AbstractJsonpControllerAdvice` setups Jackson for the JSON-P support. In my case I am getting a ready JSON object from the game server and Jackson doesn't make any actions...
So, I need to enable JSON-P support on my game server and re-sent `callback` from my aggregation server to the game server.